# What is the meaning of "outlet" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

I looked up in the dictionary but meaning of "outlet" in this sentence is not clear to me.

> He explained to the outlet that while he was serving her, his parents and wife died within an eight-month span.
>
> [Yahoo News](https://news.yahoo.com/queen-piper-woke-her-every-175747133.html)

Comment: What's the context of the sentence?

Comment: While the two answers below provide a reasonable guess as to what was meant here, it needs to be said that this use of the word is not usual, or to be recommended. Even if the full phrase *news outlet* were used, there would be something odd about characterising the organisation in question as a news outlet (something the lets the news **out**) when describing its news gathering acivities (i.e. its **in**take of the information).

Comment: I had no idea what this meant until I read the answers below. I am a native British English speaker.

Answer (score 4):

***[Outlet](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/outlet):***

> an organization that broadcasts programmes or publishes news.

(Cambridge Dictionary)

***[Media outlet](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=media%20outlet%2Cnews%20outlet&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3&case_insensitive=true) and News outlet*** appear to be expressions whose usage started around the 1960s/1970s according to Google Ngram.

From: Canada. Parliament. Senate. [Special Committee on Mass Media](https://books.google.it/books?id=sL_ZAAAAMAAJ&q=%22media%20outlet%22&dq=%22media%20outlet%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&source=gb_mobile_search&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiFgP_j_Kz6AhXVRfEDHUk4CMU4WhDoAXoECAYQAw#%22media%20outlet%22) · 1970:

> paper is published , or where a primary ( as opposed to a satellite ) TV station is located , or where one of the major groups owns a media outlet .

OP extract:

> Methven also remembered a moment when the queen showed him kindness. ***He explained to the outlet that while he was serving her, his parents and wife died within an eight-month span.*** “I was standing with the Queen and she said, 'If you're not here in the morning and you don't play the bagpipes, then I know you're away.

(yahoo.news.com)

Comment: Outlet [https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/outlet] has many meanings. It may mean a retail outlet of which she (whom he served) was a frequent customer. However when someone is talking to the outlet, it generally means a news outlet.

Answer (score 2):

"outlet" is short for "news outlet"

Most people get tired of using the same long words and phrases each day. When people write English, they usually delete words from a common phrase or delete letters from a commonly used word, in order to make their writing more concise. People used to write "telephone", but now they write "phone". The word "phone" is shorter and more convenient to use than "telephone". In less than 50 years, the word "telephone" will be archaic There existed a time in the past when more than 75% of people fluent in English were comfortable using  the word "telephone". There will exist a time in the future when fewer than 25% of fluent English speakers are comfortable reading, writing, or saying "telephone".

The word "outlet" is a shortened form of the word "news outlet".

> He explained to [***the newspaper reporter***] that while he was serving the queen, his parents and wife died within an eight-month span.

Comment: Thank you for reply. It was really helpful for me to understand.